# canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is the code I use:

```
let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL) {
  //Code
} else {
  //Showing message "Please install the Instagram application"
}
```

I am getting unsuccessful to enter in if loop.

I get this error:

> canOpenURL: failed for URL: "instagram://app" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme instagram"

I have also Login with Instagram in my device.

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL` checks to see if _your_ app can open the URL.  The error indicates that you're not allow to check if _your_ app can open an Instragram URL (because you could write malicious code to intercept URLs intended for other apps).  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Right click on your **plist file** and open it as **source code**. Then copy and paste below code:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

**Note:** One thing you have to keep in mind that it will not work on simulator. You need a real device for this.

Comment: Thank you for the note, or I would have spent several hours trying to debug my code xD

Answer (score 10):

Open your plist as source code and paste following code:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you are not registering the URL scheme in the info.plist file.

Please add this LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and add *instagram* in your info.plist and it will work.
[image]

Comment: as of 2019: the string needs to be _instagram_

Answer (score 5):

For those who try to open the app using custom URL Scheme (assume that app FirstApp opens SecondApp):

- In FirstApp add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` with URL Scheme to Info.plist like this:

[image]

- In SecondApp register new URL Scheme in URL Types like this:

[image]