# Objective C (IOS): Open URL in specific application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to open a URL in a specific app, instead its opening in Safari by default. Is there a way I can avoid the "Open In Snapchat" from Safari and just open directly in Snapchat?

Here is how I am opening the URL:

```
NSURL *snapchatURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.snapchat.com/add/username"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:snapchatURL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:snapchatURL];
}
```

Comment: You are missing the keywords "URL Schemes" or "Deep linking". Depending on the app having public scheme or not, you usually can "open the app", but maybe not do what you want (like opening in a specific view), ie with parameters in the URL.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975915/canopenurl-failed-for-url-instagram-app-error-this-app-is-not-allowed for instance

Answer (score 0):

You can use LaunchServices to test whether an application can open specific URL and to open a URL with the default or specific application.

Look at [LSCanURLAcceptURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1441854-lscanurlaccepturl), [LSOpenCFURLRef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1442850-lsopencfurlref), [LSOpenFromURLSpec](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/1441986-lsopenfromurlspec)

The LSOpenFromURLSpec is probably the one you need.

Note: URLs can start with any scheme, not just "http", "https", "ftp", "file", or "mailto". Every application can register an arbitrary set of URL schemes it can open. LaunchServices tell you if the app can open your scheme or not.